# Optional string format

Tags: python, string

Is it possible to improve this code:

```
if isinstance(value, bool) and value:
    cms = "%s %s" % (cms, usage_map["switches"][switch])
else:
    cms = "%s %s %s" % (cms, usage_map["switches"][switch], value)
```

To use in just one line? Making the value optional?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is likely a better fit for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: While more than one line, the above code is quite clear (other than needing to do some type-checking on `value` ;-).  You can probably find something shorter, but I doubt you'll find something significantly _better_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
cms = '{} {}{}'.format(
    cms, usage_map["switches"][switch],
    '' if isinstance(value, bool) and value else ' {}'.format(value)
)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure that I would consider this _better_ than what OP already has...

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
cms = "%s %s" % (cms, usage_map["switches"][switch])
if isinstance(value, bool) and value:
    cms += " %s" % value
```

Also, I think you could rewrite the condition as: `if value is True:`.